# Flutter How to reach into Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> inner map

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-future

I need help with my flutter code which involves firebasefirestore.
This is my code. I'd like to retrieve from the database the image_url from the map.

```
    final userData = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
    .get();
```

But in userData is not a map exactly.
It is a Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>.
This is what get returns . My question is, how do I scope into the Map<String, dynamic> ?
I mean to get the userData['image_url']... ? Because I get this error:
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'.
Thanks alot!

Comment: if it is a future function you need to add await keyword in front of it. Here; final userData = await FirebaseFirestore...    .Then you can reach the value

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the Firebase documentation on [getting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart_1), that'd be:

```
final docRef = db.collection("users").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid);
docRef.get().then(
  (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    // ...
  },
  onError: (e) => print("Error getting document: $e"),
);
```

You can also use `await` as Timur commented, in which case it'd be:

```
final docRef = db.collection("users").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid);
DocumentSnapshot doc = await docRef.get();
final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
// ...
```